# Calculate the values for shmmax & shmmni parameters in redhat kernel tuning

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, kernel, linux-kernel

How to calculate shmmax & shmmni values and define in redhat very first time. I want to understand the math behind it. I can see a large number in my kernel parameters what is that big number and how is that related to physical ram?
I've 128GB ram and SHMMAX="123695063040"

Answer (score 1):

**According to Red Hat documentation at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1437883 (access may be limited to Red Hat authorized customers):**

- In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1, default value for kernel.shmmax and kernel.shmall have changed.
- Default value for kernel.shmmax and kernel.shmall have been changed within Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1, to comply with the values set in the upstream kernel. The new default values for kernel.shmmax and kernel.shmall are set to 18446744073692774399.
- Calculation for new default values is done, using the following formula in the kernel code:

```
include/uapi/linux/shm.h
[...]
#define SHMMAX (ULONG_MAX - (1L<<24))    /* max shared seg size (bytes) */
#define SHMALL (ULONG_MAX - (1L<<24))    /* max shm system wide (pages) */
```

Comment: What would be SHMALL & SHMMAX for a 32GB redhat 7 machine?